# If correlation does not imply causation, then what will it take to infer a causal relationship?

Tags: correlation

Basically the title. What statistical quantity can be used to confirm a causal relationship if not correlation?

Comment: Also have a look [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/319678/how-to-find-causality-in-data)

Comment: Yes both of these are great thanks!