# Isn't it okay to correlate acceleration with calorie regardless whether acceleration contains gravity or not?

Tags: correlation, pearson-r, spearman-rho, kendall-tau

**What I am trying to do?**

Let's think, there are some diabetic patients and I am interested to find whether acceleration *(when they will run to do physical exercise)* correlates with amount of spent calories. I am counting spent calories and acceleration of different axes (x, y, z) via a device.

**Then, what does create the problem?**

I am calculating the magnitude of acceleration by using the formula: *square_root(x^2+y^2+z^2)*. Then, I will correlate acceleration with spent calories. However, I do not know whether the accelerometer calculates acceleration including or excluding gravity. Therefore, there may have error in measuring magnitude of acceleration.

**After that, what do I think?**

If I would want to know each participant's magnitude of acceleration, then I must had to know whether the accelerometer calculates acceleration including or excluding gravity. If it would include gravity, I had to exclude it to find magnitude of acceleration. However, as I want to just calculate the correlation coefficient *(using Spearman, Pearson, Kendall's Tau etc.)*, therefore, it may not need to be concerned whether acceleration includes gravity or not.

**But, what is the motivation behind the thought?**

Let's think, the accelerometer calculates acceleration including gravity. Then, each time, it measures acceleration, that gravity *(there can be negligible variation of gravity, each time it measures)* will be included. That is why I think, this will not create a problem in measuring correlation coefficient as [correlation does not change when the units of measurement change](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/wmopen-concepts-statistics/chapter/linear-relationships-4-of-4/) *(I am assuming one type of unit when gravity is included and another type of unit when gravity is excluded)*.

**At the end, my question?**

Will it be problematic if I want to correlate acceleration (by calculating magnitude of acceleration) with spent calorie without considering whether gravity is included or excluded from acceleration?

*Any kind of suggestion or help will be greatly appreciated!*

Comment: In what sense does "including gravity" constitute a mere change of units of measurement??

Comment: In Physics, acceleration is a strength while calories are energy. Spent calories will constantly increase while acceleration will alternate between increasing and decreasing. How would you correlate them?

Comment: @whuber Thanks for your response. I am not telling that "including gravity" constitute a **_mere_** change of units of measurement". Rather, I am thinking in the way that adding gravity will give you one value and exclusion of gravity will give you another value. Hence, it **seems** to be like converting from one unit to another unit.

Comment: @manu190466 Thanks for your comment. Is there any sentence like _"If one variable increases and another variable alternate between increase and decrease, we will not be able to use any existing formula to find correlation"_? I think, it may not be true. There are many ways to find correlation, even if we fail to find correlation using the general formula: Pearson, Spearman, Kendall's tau etc. On the other hand, here, I focused on acceleration and added calorie to make a complete problem. If you feel that calorie can not be correlated, then, you may set any variable along with **acceleration**.

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to ask.  One possibility is that you are unsure whether to use $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ as a variable in a model or $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+(z-g)^2},$ where the $z$-axis is up and $g$ is the gravitational contribution to acceleration. (If so, this should make it clear that the problem is not one of changing a unit of measurement.) The answer ultimately depends on your instrument, so why not consult its documentation?

Comment: @whuber Thanks for your response. I have tried my best to make the question clear. I feel sorry that I have failed. My question was _"Is it okay, if I want to correlate acceleration with spent calorie without considering whether gravity is included or excluded from acceleration?"_ I failed to ask the device builder whether his device calculates acceleration including or excluding gravity. He lives in another country and is currently unavailable.