# Why does presence of sample correlation violate independence assumption?

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, correlation, independence, assumptions

Consider the data from [this website](http://onlinestatbook.com/2/tests_of_means/correlated.html).

They present the attached graph and state

> "It is clear that children who get more correct in the D0 condition
>   tend to get more correct in the D60 condition. The correlation between
>   the two conditions is high: r = 0.80. Clearly these two variables are
>   not independent."

**Why does correlation here mean that independence is violated?**

The definition of independence on wikipedia says:

> "two random variables are independent if the realization of one does
>   not affect the probability distribution of the other."

I don't see how the presence of correlation implies that one variable affects the probability distribution of the other.

I mean, we can ASSUME that one variable being high affects the probability of the other variable being high. But here they are not stating it as an assumption but as a truth.

- Why can it not be the case that there is some individual-specific factor at play? For example, Maybe certain subjects have a lot more probability mass on the right tail. This would give correlation, but I don't think it means that one variable being large affects the probability of the other variable being large

  [image: Image from cited website showing correlation]

(Aside: To whoever upvoted this prior to the major edit, my apologies if I have inadvertently changed what you were most interested in)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Under what conditions does correlation imply causation?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/534/under-what-conditions-does-correlation-imply-causation)

Answer (score 0):

The value $0.80$ is such a high correlation that it’s basically impossible to get that kind of value from independent variables. You can (more or less) quantify this unlikeliness with a p-value, but you know going into the test that you’re going to reject a null hypothesis of zero correlation.

Do note that correlation is not necessary for dependence, as a post on Data Science discusses: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/72824/what-is-the-meaning-of-a-quadratic-relation-when-r-0/72826#72826.

Answer (score 0):

Both you and the authors of the [analysis you quote](http://onlinestatbook.com/2/tests_of_means/correlated.html) are correct, but there is clarification to be made.

The above-mentioned authors are correct in saying that the two variables, $D0$ (outcome under placebo) and $D60$ (outcome under treatment) are not independent because each observation, consisting of a vector $(D0_i,D60_i)$, is an observation of outcomes under placebo and treatment **for the same individual $i$**.

At the same time, you are correct to note that they state "Clearly these two variables are not independent" right after they say "The [sample] correlation between the two conditions is high: r=0.80", almost implying the latter as the reason for the former. Observing such a high correlation value based on a sample size of 24 makes it quite unlikely that the two variables are independent. A very rare event, but not an impossible one. The simulation below uses two i.i.d. random variables with a pdf that seems reasonable for this study to generate 10,000 random samples and calculate the correlation in each of these. In the particular 10,000 random samples displayed below, I found one sample with a correlation above 0.8.

Take  $var1$ and $var2$ to be two identically distributed random variables, with the pdf given by $$f(y)=2*e^{-2y},  y>0$$

Using the inverse transform method, you can verify that the Inverse CDF is given by $-\frac{1}{2} ln(1-x)$, which explains why $var1$ and $var2$ below are assigned this expression.

```
install.packages("ggplot2")
library("ggplot2")

nobs<-24
x<-runif(nobs)
var1<--log(1-x)/2
x<-runif(nobs)
var2<--log(1-x)/2
df<-as.data.frame(cbind(var1,var2))
ggplot(df)+geom_point(aes(x=var1,y=var2))
```

Here is what one sample of 24 observations looks like:

[image: Showing that the pdf used in the simulation is reasonable]

```
vector_of_cor<-NULL
for (i in 1:10000) {
    x<-runif(nobs)
    var1<--log(1-x)/2
    x<-runif(nobs)
    var2<--log(1-x)/2
    vector_of_cor<-c(vector_of_cor,cor(var1,var2))
}

df<-as.data.frame(vector_of_cor)
ggplot(df)+geom_histogram(aes(x=vector_of_cor,fill=vector_of_cor>=0.8),bins = 100)
```

Here is what what the correlations of the 10,000 samples look like:

[image]

[image]