# Teaching examples for internal validity: published experiments later shown to be confounded in an interesting way

Tags: causality, confounding, validity, spurious-correlation

There are some good examples of interesting/fun spurious correlations here ([Examples for teaching: Correlation does not mean causation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/36/examples-for-teaching-correlation-does-not-mean-causation)). Many/most of these are "funny" examples that aren't likely to affect real life decision making. In contrast, this thread ([Real examples of Correlation confused with Causation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/109129/real-examples-of-correlation-confused-with-causation)) has some interesting examples of real-life misinterpretation of spurious correlations.

I'm wondering if anyone has cool/interesting favorites along the lines of the second thread, for a related-but-different phenomenon: published *experiments* (i.e., not correlational data) whose results were later discovered to be confounded in an interesting/unexpected/memorable way.

Answer (score 2):

There is one example explained in Causality (2009) p. 358:

> ... a study involving injected vitamin E as a treatment
>   for incubated children at risk for retrolental fibroplasia. The
>   randomized experiment indicated efficacy for the injections, but it
>   was soon discovered that the actual effective treatment was opening
>   the pressurized, oxygen-saturated incubators several times per day to
>   give the injections, thus lowering the barometric pressure and oxygen
>   levels in the blood of the infants.

The problem here was that experimenters were not only doing $X$ (vitamin E injection), but doing $X$ and $Z$ (vitamin injection and opening the incubator), thus what they thought was the effect of one intervention ($X$) was in fact the effect of another ($Z$).  This could have been detected with a placebo group in the study.